# What is the meaning of the probability that one event or random variable is an element of another?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

I recently came across the formula $\Pr(X \in B\ |\ X \in A) = \int_B f_{X\ |\ A}(x)\ dx$ in a Probability Theory class.  I understand what the $|$ symbol means, but what is the meaning of an expression like $\Pr(E \in F)$, where $E$ and $F$ could be events or random variables?  Is this identical to a $\Pr()$ expression involving only $\cap$, $\cup$, $\neg$, and $|$?

Comment: You could think of it as the probability that the observed value of the random variable $X$ is an element of the set $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here $X$ is a random variable and $B$ and $A$ are sets (presumably subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, not events or random variables as you seem to suggest).  So, $X\in A$ is an event: it stands for the set $\{\omega\in\Omega:X(\omega)\in A\}$, where $\Omega$ is the sample space.

Comment: So is $\Pr(X \in B\ |\ X \in A)$ equivalent to $\Pr(B\ |\ A)$?  I'm envisioning the Venn diagrams for the two as being the same.

Comment: $\Pr(B\ |\ A)$ is meaningless because $B$ and $A$ are *not* events.  They are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, not of the sample space.